# it makes a lot of sense?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

> Don’t spend your whole life working in order to get something that is
>   probably beyond your reach anyway. It’s far better to live in a simple
>   way. If your desires are simple they are easy to satisfy and you will
>   have the time and energy to enjoy the things that matter. That was his
>   recipe for happiness, and **it makes a lot of sense**.

A little history of philosophy, Nigel Warburton

What does "it makes a lot of sense" mean? I think it means "It is very reasonable" Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, your interpretation is correct.

Answer (score 3):

**To make sense** means **to be practical and sensible**, or **to be easy to understand** (Macmillan Dictionary).

I'm inclined to believe that in the context of your passage, "to make sense" is used in its first meaning. So, you are right. To make *a lot of* sense = to be *very* reasonable/practical and sensible.